# How can unreachable code cause my program to crash?

Tags: c++, windows

I have a function like this:

```
bool func(args) {
   execute_something();

   return true;

   /* code that is optionally included or omitted, with no source code change above the return statement */
}
```

Including the code block causes the program to exit before execute_something() is reached, but omitting it allows it to run fine. What am I missing?

To clarify the question: I'm curious to know if such a behavior is even possible, given the way I have described it.

Comment: Show a [mre] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I suppose nobody can help you with the code that you have provided. Try to explain it a little bit more.

Comment: can you give more details?

Comment: Having Undefined Behaviour anywhere in a program can affect unexpected parts of the code (like crashing on code which should never be executed). This being said, we have too little information to say anything conclusive.

Comment: Something somewhere in your code has undefined behaviour. Start by working your way backwards from the code before the return to the beginning of the program, looking for trouble. If there's no problem in that direction, try the other direction.

Comment: Thanks Yksisarvinen and molbdnilo. That's helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can. In fact you don't even need to call the function at all for the code block after `return true;` to cause undefined behavior. Example:

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename>
auto var = []{
    int* i;
    return *i; // undefined behavior!
}();

bool func() {
   return true;
   (void)(var<int>); // UB if and only if line included
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "This is main!"; // Also forces static initialization not to be deferred forever
}
```

If the line after `return true;` is present, `var<int>` will be intantiated and its initializer will be executed at runtime, causing undefined behavior. If the line is not present `var<int>` is not instantiated and the code with undefined behavior is never executed.

See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/eJ5pHK) with GCC 9.2 and `-O2` for demonstration. With the line the program crashes (return value 255) and without it it prints the `cout` statement correctly and returns success (return value 0).

---

These are however very specific cases and it is much more likely that, if you observe a crash, there is undefined behavior somewhere else in your program and it happens to manifest as crash only if the lines after the return statement are present, because undefined behavior is unpredictable like that. See the comments on the question.